# Show and hide a Form when click at tr of table

Tags: jquery, html, css

When i click to tr of table the display of class (modifier) change to block but when i click to submit button i don't know why the class(modifier) it's Disappears.

this is Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .modifier {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-Afficher">
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Code</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>PO 500</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modifier">
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="Entrer le nouveaux Code......">
            <input type="submit" value="Enregistre" name="Enregistre">
            <p><?php if (isset($message)): echo $message; endif;?></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="JavaScript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $('.table-Afficher tbody tr').click(
                function () {
                    $('.modifier').css('display', 'block');
                }
            )
        }
    )
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: because when you submit a form you reload the page !

Comment: When you click on your `submit` button, the form is sent to the same page, which means the page loads again from scratch, hence applying the `display: none;` style to your `modifier` element.

Comment: Ok i understand thank you.
But  i want  in first show the result of submit button and  put something like Button when the user click at the button the form is Disappears

Comment: are you using any server side language ?? Because that can be done by using one .

Comment: I don't know what do you mean But i'm using PHP